# Factorise a decreasing function

Tags: functions

I have this code, how can I simplify it to a formula with x and y?

```
while y>0
x*y + x*(y-1) + x*(y-2)...
```

example:

```
x=0.5 and y=3
=> 0.5*3 + 0.5*2 + 0.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $y$ is a positive integer, the expression is equal to $x (y + (y-1) + (y-2) + \cdots + 1)$.

The quantity $y + (y-1) + \cdots + 1$ is the sum of the first $y$ positive integers, i.e. the $y$th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) which has a well-known formula $\frac{y(y+1)}{2}$.

---

More generally, if $y > 0$, let $\{y\} = y - \lfloor y \rfloor$ denote the fractional part of $y$. Then the expression is $x(y + (y-1)  +\cdots + (\{y\}+1) + \{y\})$. The term in parentheses is the sum of an arithmetic sequence; one can show it to be $\frac{(y + \{y\}) (\lfloor y \rfloor + 1)}{2}$.

(You can see that for integer $y$, we have $\{y\}=0$ and $\lfloor y \rfloor = y$, so that this expression reduces to $\frac{y(y+1)}{2}$ as I mentioned above.)

Comment: Must $y$ be an integer?

Comment: @Henry Thanks, updated my answer